# Is there a way to share iPad's (second generation) Internet with MacBook? (tethering)

Tags: ipad, internet, internet-sharing, tethering

I have searched endlessly on the Internet to find a solution, but haven't found a single useful thing. So I'll ask you guys. Is there any way to share iPad 2's 3G Internet with my MacBook ? If possible without jailbreak? If it is impossible, does anyone know ways around it to make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [HTML5 app](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2158760/tether-apples-ios-censors-html5-app) which will allow you to turn your iPhone into a personal hotspot without any jailbreak or extra apps. I don't know if it will work on iPad though...

And a second solution is not what you want to hear. The most easy solution is to jailbreak it indeed. There is an app in the Cydia store called [TetherMe](http://www.chrisdata.com/tetherme-enable-native-tethering-on-iphone-cydia/) (**$1.99**). And it will allow yout to turn your iPad in a personal hotspot within the minute. It's super easy to install and very useful when you're in a desperate need of a 3G connection.

And these days, [jailbreaking is as easy as it was before](http://www.jailbreaknation.com/jailbreak-5.1.1-untethered-ios-with-absinthe-2.0-iphone-4s43gs-ipad-321-ipod-touch-4g3g), so I'm not sure why people are against it since you won't lose your warranty or anything alike...